# Вычислить используя неявный метод Эйлера

Tags: delphi, математика

[image: Формула]

```
for i:=1 to n do
   begin
      Y[i]:=(D1*Y[i-1])+(D2*X[i])+D3*Z[i];
      Z[i]:=(Z[i-1]*D4)+(D5*Y[i]);
   end;
```

Ошибка при вычислении, так как  на i шаге цикла, при попытке вычислить значение Y[i] еще нет значения переменной Z[i], а при вычислении значения Z[i] используется неверное значение Y[i]. При этом Excel формулу правильно вычисляет.
Ссылка на Excel документ https://yadi.sk/i/3Y2kTR2ErTgBg

Answer (score 2):

Нужно инициализировать переменные:

```
Y[0]:=0;
Z[0]:=0;
```

Раз нужно вычислять значение обеих переменных `Y[i]` и `Z[i]` одновременно, то проведём несложное математическое преобразование. Введём переменную `C`, равную

```
C = Y[i] - Z[i]*D3
```

Получаем:

```
Z[i] = Z[i-1]*D4 + (C + Z[i]*D3)*D5
```

То есть `Z[i]` равен

```
Z[i] = (Z[i-1]*D4 + C*D5) / (1 - D3*D5)
```

Теперь перепишем алгоритм вычисления:

```
for i:=1 to n do
 begin
  С:=(D1*Y[i-1])+(D2*X[i]);
  Z[i]:=(Z[i-1]*D4+D5*С)/(1-D3*D5);
  Y[i]:=С+D3*Z[i];
 end;
```

Comment: при вычислении  D3*Z[i]  даст 0
ссылка на вычисление в Exel https://yadi.sk/i/3Y2kTR2ErTgBg

Comment: Это же не Excel, а Pascal. Переменные должны быть инициализированы перед использованием.

Comment: Я выложил кусочек кода, все переменные инициализированы. Вопрос в том как сделать вычисление переменных одновременно.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял задачу, тут простая математика. Условие состоит из двух уравнений, в которых всего две неизвестные: `y[i]` и `z[i]`.

```
y[i] = y[i-1]*d1 +x[i]*d2 + z[i]*d3
z[i] = z[i-1]*d4 + y[i]*d5
```

А такие вещи решаются очень легко, методом подстановки выражения из первого уравнения во второе.

Следите за руками:

1. Вместо `y[i]` во второе уравнение подставляем его значение:

`z[i] = z[i-1]*d4 + d5*(y[i-1]*d1 +x[i]*d2 + z[i]*d3)`

2. Делим обе части уравнения на `d5`:

`z[i]/d5 = z[i-1]*d4/d5 + y[i-1]*d1 +x[i]*d2 + z[i]*d3`

3. Переносим `z[i]*d3` в левую часть:

`z[i]/d5 - z[i]*d3 = z[i-1]*d4/d5 + y[i-1]*d1 +x[i]*d2`

4. Умножаем обратно на `d5`:

`z[i] - z[i]*d3*d5 = z[i-1]*d4 + (y[i-1]*d1 +x[i]*d2)*d5`

5. В левой части выносим `z[i]` за скобки:

`z[i]*(1 - d3*d5) = z[i-1]*d4 + (y[i-1]*d1 +x[i]*d2)*d5`

6. Делим обе части на `(1 - d3*d5)`:

`z[i] = (z[i-1]*d4 + (y[i-1]*d1 +x[i]*d2)*d5) / (1 - d3*d5)`

И вот теперь мы знаем как вычислить `z[i]`, которое не зависит от `y[i]`.

Следовательно, решение:

```
// инициализация
for i := 0 to n do begin
  x[i] := ???
end;

y[0] := ???
z[0] := ??? 

// вычисление
for i := 1 to n do begin
    z[i] := (z[i-1]*d4 + (y[i-1]*d1 +x[i]*d2)*d5) / (1 - d3*d5);
    y[i] := y[i-1]*d1 +x[i]*d2 + z[i]*d3;  
end;
```